# LWC @api is not working in experience builder while logged in as community user

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, lightning-experience, profile, parent-to-child

the main problem i have with this, is that it works well when i'm editing builder as Admin, but when i try to log as specific user, the ID's are not passed within the LWC'c

I will show on example:

First LWC looks like this, which is basically parent

[image: parent LWC]

and this is my second LWC, which is basically (another) child

[image: child LWC]

anyone got any ideas why this works on System Admin but not on specific profile?

EDIT: added some code snippets
apex controller, and yes, user have access to the "Byt__c" object because as shown in first image, he can see the list which consists of "Byt__c" object

```
public with sharing class DashboardController {

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Byt__c getByt(String bytId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Etapa__c, Vchod__c,slo_ZoBKZ_KZ__c, Ozna_enie__c, Typ__c, Izbovos__c, Account__c
        FROM Byt__c WHERE Id=: bytId LIMIT 1];
    }
```

this is the "parent" lwc
parent.JS has  `@api flatID;` (which i know it holds what ID)

and parrent.HTML

```
                <c-dashboard
                        flat-i-d={flatID} onstandard={showTemplateOrStandard} onklz={showTemplateOrKLZ}>
                </c-dashboard>
            </lightning-tab>
```

CHILD.JS is exposed to that variable - ``` @api flatID;

````
and in the same class used in that dashboardController 

```  getBytData() {
        console.log("flatid;;;;"+this.flatID);

            getByt({ bytId: this.flatID })
            .then(response => {
                this.bytData = response;

            })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                })
}
````

i mean, look, i don't there is problem with my code as it works smoothly when System Administrator is logged in, i think the problem is with some security settings in ORG for that specific profile that is disabling correct LWC functionality

Comment: Is `DashboardController` with sharing? If so, can the users access to those records? Could you please edit your question adding the code of DashboardController class (copy-paste the code, do not include it as a screenshot)

Comment: When adding the code, just add relevant snippets, not the whole component. Make sure to include the component template parts, the component JavaScript class declaration, the relevant `@api` properties and the functions that are involved in this specific handling. You'll also need to include snippets of any `@AuraEnabled` methods that are relevant.

Comment: RubenDG's comment is still valid; the Apex is `with sharing` so it is possible that the user does not have sharing access to all the `Byt__c` records...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a class referenced directly from an LWC is defined as `with sharing` or `inherited sharing` Salesforce enforces sharing rules, so Apex code will run in the current user context.
That's why with an administrator you'll be able to query every record, while with a profile that lacks `view all data` permission or `view all` on object permission, if the OWD of an object is Private, you'll retrieve only records owned or shared with the user.

So, in order to fix that error, you could either:

- [create a sharing rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rules_create.htm&type=5) (criteria or owner-based) to grant record access to those users
- change the class definition to `without sharing`, if you want to let every user with access to `DashboardController` class query all records.

You can read more on with/without sharing keywords [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm).